# Shortest branch in a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, pseudocode

A binary tree can be encoded using two functions `l` and `r`
such that for a `node n`, `l(n)` give the left child of `n`, `r(n)`
give the right child of `n`.

A branch of a tree is a path from the root to a leaf, the
length of a branch to a particular leaf is the number of
arcs on the path from the root to that leaf.

Let `MinBranch(l,r,x)` be a simple recursive algorithm for
taking a binary tree encoded by the l and r functions
together with the root node x for the binary tree and
returns the length of the shortest branch of the binary
tree.

Give the pseudocode for this algorithm.

OK, so basically this is what I've come up with so far:

```
MinBranch(l, r, x)
{
    if x is None return 0

    left_one = MinBranch(l, r, l(x))

    right_one = MinBranch(l, r, r(x))

    return {min (left_one),(right_one)}
}
```

Obviously this isn't great or perfect. I'd be greatful if
people can help me get this perfect and working - any help
will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd say your version is pretty good, don't have anything to add to it.

Comment: BTW you can also edit your question from yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339043/…)... that way you don't have to rephrase everything again.

Comment: -1 for bad title, erasing your question, and asking for people to solve your hw rather than asking for a hint about something specifically that's stumping you

Comment: Why did you erase your question?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt anyone will solve homework for you straight-up.  A clue: the return value must surely grow higher as the tree gets bigger, right?  However I don't see any numeric literals in your function except 0, and no addition operators either.  How will you ever return larger numbers?

Another angle on the same issue: *anytime* you write a recursive function, it helps to enumerate "what are all the conditions where I should stop calling myself?  what I return in each circumstance?"

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right approach, but you're not quite there; your recursive algorithm will always return 0. (the logic is almost right, though...)

note that the length of the sub-branches is one less than the length of the branch; so `left_one` and `right_one` should be `1 + MinBranch...`.

Steping through the algorithm with some sample trees will help uncover off-by-one errors like this one...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you almost have it, but consider this example:

```
      4

   3     5
```

When you trace through `MinBranch`, you'll see that in your
`MinBranch(l,r,4)` call:

```
left_one = MinBranch(l, r, l(x))
         = MinBranch(l, r, l(4))
         = MinBranch(l, r, 3)
         = 0
```

That makes sense, after all, 3 is a leaf node, so of course the distance
to the closest leaf node is 0. The same happens for right_one.

But you then wind up here:

```
return {min (left_one),(right_one)}
     = {min (0), (0) }
     = 0
```

but that's clearly wrong, because this node (4) is not a leaf node. Your
code forgot to count the current node (oops!). I'm sure you can manage
to fix that.

---

Now, actually, they way you're doing this isn't the fastest, but I'm not
sure if that's relevant for this exercise. Consider this tree:

```
         4
       3   5
     2
   1
```

Your algorithm will count up the left branch recursively, even though it
could, hypothetically, bail out if you first counted the right branch
and noted that 3 has a left, so its clearly longer than 5 (which is a
leaf). But, of course, counting the right branch first doesn't always
work!

Instead, with more complicated code, and probably a tradeoff of greater
memory usage, you can check nodes left-to-right, top-to-bottom (just
like English reading order) and stop at the first leaf you find.

Comment: oh shit :| erm so if i do 1+minbranch(l,r,l(x)) it works out right?

Comment: @rachel: I think so, but you should try it out on some trees to check. After all, you lose the points if it doesn't, not me :-D

Comment: thanks dero for editing and helping me multiple times - thing is im not concerned with time and memory since its a purely theoretical question :)

Answer (score 0):

What you've created can be thought of as a depth-first search.  However, given what you're after (shortest branch), this may not be the most efficent approach.  Think about how your algorithm would perform on a tree that was very heavy on the left side (of the root node), but had only one node on the right side.

Hint:  consider a breadth-first search approach.

Comment: thanks will try and come up with a better solution using bfs cheers :)

Comment: If you're after efficiency then BFS is not much better -- you are just trading time cost for space cost.  IDDFS combines the best attributes of both with only a small overhead.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there looks like a depth first search algorithm which will have to search the entire tree before you come up with a solution. what you need is the [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm which can return as soon as it finds the solution without doing a complete search

Comment: +1 this is what I was going to suggest. Breadth first search using a queue (or stack) is the right approach to find the shallowest leaf node (which is the other way to express this problem).

Comment: While your comment is helpful for solving the problem in general, I must downvote because it is not very helpful for the *homework* problem. Particularly because the student is required to use and define MinBranch over particular arguments, and I do not see how to sanely implement a BFS algorithm with such restrictions. If I'm wrong, consider the sign of my vote reversed. :)